# Why is onReceivedError() not working in all Android phones?

Tags: java, android, webview

My `onReceivedError()` is not working on all Android phones. It only works on a few. What could be the cause of this?

This for my new `onRecievedError()`

```
  superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            //here you can do something when received error in WebView

            superWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    superWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            superProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

     });
```

I expect the app to run in all Android that can install.
Has anyone encounter this kind of error before?